# Translate Animation is hiding behind other view

Tags: android, android-layout, animation, android-linearlayout, translate-animation

I have two linear layouts inside relative layout.Each linear layout has three pictures in it.thus forming a grid of pictures with three pictures placed horizontally in first linear layout and three in the second below above.As Shown below

[image: images 1,2,3 are in top linear layout and 4,5,6 in bottom linear layout]

My xml code for grid is :

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/picturesLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/titleCaption"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp" >


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llimages"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/ivPrimaryProfile"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/ivPrimaryProfile"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ivPrimaryProfile"
         android:layout_marginTop="5dp"

        >

        <RelativeLayout 
android:layout_width="60dp"
android:layout_height="60dp"
android:id="@+id/rl2" 
android:gravity="center"
>

         <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivProfile2"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"

        android:layout_gravity="center"

        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/addphoto" />

         <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivCross2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/ivProfile2"
        android:src="@drawable/cross_white"
        android:visibility="gone" />

         </RelativeLayout>
         <View 
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="60dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
             />
          <RelativeLayout 
android:layout_width="60dp"
android:layout_height="60dp"
android:id="@+id/rl3" 
android:gravity="center"
>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivProfile3"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"

        android:layout_gravity="center"



        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/addphoto" />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivCross3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/ivProfile3"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/ivProfile3"
        android:src="@drawable/cross_white"
        android:visibility="gone" />
    </RelativeLayout>
    <View 
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="60dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
             />
<RelativeLayout 
android:layout_width="60dp"
android:layout_height="60dp"
 android:id="@+id/rl4" 
android:gravity="center"
>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivProfile4"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"

        android:layout_gravity="center"



        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/addphoto" />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivCross4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/ivProfile4"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/ivProfile4"
        android:src="@drawable/cross_white"
        android:visibility="gone" />
        </RelativeLayout>


    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/ivPrimaryProfile"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/ivPrimaryProfile"
        android:layout_below="@+id/llimages"
         android:layout_marginTop="5dp"

        >

        <RelativeLayout 
android:layout_width="60dp"
android:layout_height="60dp"
 android:id="@+id/rl5" 
android:gravity="center"
>
         <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivProfile5"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"

        android:layout_gravity="center"

        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/addphoto" />

         <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivCross5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/ivProfile5"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/ivProfile5"
        android:src="@drawable/cross_white"
        android:visibility="gone" />
         <View 
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="60dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
             />
                    </RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout 
android:layout_width="60dp"
android:layout_height="60dp"
 android:id="@+id/rl6" 
android:gravity="center"
>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivProfile6"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"

        android:layout_gravity="center"



        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/addphoto" />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivCross6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/ivProfile6"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/ivProfile6"
        android:src="@drawable/cross_white"
        android:visibility="gone" />
    </RelativeLayout>
    <View 
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="60dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
             />
<RelativeLayout 
android:layout_width="60dp"
android:layout_height="60dp"
 android:id="@+id/rl7" 
android:gravity="center"
>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivProfile7"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"

        android:layout_gravity="center"



        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/addphoto" />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivCross7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/ivProfile7"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/ivProfile7"
        android:src="@drawable/cross_white"
        android:visibility="gone" />
        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Problem :

I want images 4,5,6 to translate to image1 position.which is happening but problem is that when i translate any of 4,5,6 image they translate behind image1 (translate animation hides behind top linear layout)

My translate animation is given :

```
TranslateAnimation anim = new TranslateAnimation( 0, toX - fromX , 0, toY -        fromY );

    anim.setDuration(500);
    anim.setFillAfter( true );

    view.startAnimation(anim);
```

I am sure translate animation code has no issue.something wrong with my layout

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [setZAdjustment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.html#setZAdjustment(int)).

```
Constant    Value   Description
normal      0       The content being animated be kept in its current Z order.
top         1       The content being animated is forced on top of all other content for the duration of the animation.
bottom     -1       The content being animated is forced under all other content for the duration of the animation.
```

Answer (score 0):

`setZAdjustment` or `android:translationZ` and `android:elevation` are only for API 21 (Lollipop) and above. So it is better you place the animated view **below** the top view in the XML inside a `LinearLayout`.

Then set the top view background to the same color as the window. Use `android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"` to set the default color. Then translate the animated view towards the top view and it will create an effect that the animated view is disappearing behind the top view. I hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

`android:zAdjustment` [works only with window animations](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/2xVkWWY2oBU) (present since beggining, API 1)

`android:translationZ` and `android:elevation` works since API 21

`View` "on top" is the last drawn, so last in XML (last child of particular `ViewGroup`), even when animating/translating.

Positioning/ordering inside `RelativeLayout` it's easy - use aligning to parent edges and other views inside parent.

For `LinearLayout` you should subclass and override method [`getChildDrawingOrder`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#getChildDrawingOrder(int,%20int)), which is applicable also for all other `ViewGroup` subclasses (even `RelativeLayout` if you prefer instead of aligning):

```
@Override
protected int getChildDrawingOrder(int childCount, int i) {
    return (childCount - 1) - i; //reversed drawing order
}
```

don't forget to add also this line in constructors:

```
setChildrenDrawingOrderEnabled(true); //required!
```

for `i=0` you should return position of first child `View` to draw, for `i=childCount-1` return position of `View` last to draw (will be on top of other). By default method returns `i`, so first `View` in XML is first drawn

note that you can't use `translationX` (or Y) and move "outside" `ViewGroup` (parent) bounds